# Spring Boot Batch with Oracle as JobRepository

Tags: oracle, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, spring-java-config, spring-batch-admin

I am searching for some good example of Spring Boot Batch where Oracle DB is used as Job Repository with Java Config.I have been able to run the batch with embedded DB.But while trying to use the Spring Batch Admin, am facing problems.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: **am facing problems** ?? Be explicit about what problems?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of Spring Boot with Spring Batch Admin.
https://github.com/codecentric/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot

All you need to do is replace batch-hsql.properties with batch-oracle.properties and add
`-Denvironment=oracle` property to your server.